# WPF TreeView Slow Loading

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a tree view like this

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvFolders" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" 
  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
  BorderBrush="{StaticResource ColligoBorderLightBrush}"
  IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False" 
  IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
  VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
  Loaded="tvFolders_Loaded">

</TreeView>
```

The binding TreeItems is an ObservableCollection.

If this tree is not very large, this works great but if I have many folders/subfolders structure it can take 10 seconds or so until it loads.

How do I solve the issue so tree is built faster?

Comment: You can try lazy loading. First load all the main folders, once click on the main folder, then load all the subfolders to it. You are using all the primitives and only way to load faster is lazy loading

Comment: If I could get some hints how to do that, that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading can be done as mentioned below. Since it not good practice to post any links. I am posting links as well as code content in the link.

I got it from here. http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/lazy-loading-treeview-items/

```
 <Grid>
    <TreeView Name="trvStructure" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded" Margin="10" />
</Grid>

 public partial class LazyLoadingSample : Window
    {
            public LazyLoadingSample()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
                    foreach(DriveInfo driveInfo in drives)
                            trvStructure.Items.Add(CreateTreeItem(driveInfo));
            }

            public void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                    TreeViewItem item = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
                    if((item.Items.Count == 1) && (item.Items[0] is string))
                    {
                            item.Items.Clear();

                            DirectoryInfo expandedDir = null;
                            if(item.Tag is DriveInfo)
                                    expandedDir = (item.Tag as DriveInfo).RootDirectory;
                            if(item.Tag is DirectoryInfo)
                                    expandedDir = (item.Tag as DirectoryInfo);
                            try
                            {
                                    foreach(DirectoryInfo subDir in expandedDir.GetDirectories())
                                            item.Items.Add(CreateTreeItem(subDir));
                            }
                            catch { }
                    }
            }

            private TreeViewItem CreateTreeItem(object o)
            {
                    TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
                    item.Header = o.ToString();
                    item.Tag = o;
                    item.Items.Add("Loading...");
                    return item;
            }
    }
```